# Multiple rotating adjudicators inter-rater reliability

Tags: r, agreement-statistics

I am analyzing data from a clinical study. In this study, each case was ranked by two to three adjudicators. The study had a panel of six adjudicators. Each case was adjudicated by two primary adjudicators. In case of a disagreement between the two adjudicators, a third adjudication was introduced to break the tie.

Here is a data sample

```
adjdata <- data.frame(
  J1=c('Yes',NA,NA,'Yes',NA,'Yes',NA),
  J2=c('Yes','Yes',NA,NA,'Yes','Yes','Yes'),
  J3=c(NA,'No','No',NA,'No',NA,'Yes'),
  J4=c(NA,'No',NA,'Yes',NA,NA,NA),
  J5=c(NA,NA,'No',NA,'Yes',NA,NA),
  J6=c('No',NA,'Yes',NA,NA,'No',NA)
)

J1   J2   J3   J4   J5   J6
1  Yes  Yes <NA> <NA> <NA>   No
2 <NA>  Yes   No   No <NA> <NA>
3 <NA> <NA>   No <NA>   No  Yes
4  Yes <NA> <NA>  Yes <NA> <NA>
5 <NA>  Yes   No <NA>  Yes <NA>
6  Yes  Yes <NA> <NA> <NA>   No
7 <NA>  Yes  Yes <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

**What is the appropriate statistical method to calculate the inter-rater reliability for such study design?**

I tried running Fleiss kappa but I kept the following error

```
irr::kappam.fleiss(adjdata)
Error in ratings[i, ] : subscript out of bounds
```

I would appreciate any guidance or feedback.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal you are pursuing with your analysis? There are multiple metrics to analyse this problem, all with their strengths and weaknesses. For example, you can just count the fraction of cases in which the adjudicators agreed vs all cases. Is that good enough?

Comment: My goal is to measure the inter-rater reliability and generate some statistics analogous to cohen kappa in principle that  I can report in the scientific literature.